# How to prove distributive property of a determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, determinant

How to prove that $|A\cdot B| = |A|\cdot|B|$ where A and B are square matrices of the same size?

P.S.: This proof is not mentioned in my textbook, nor was I able to find it on the web.

Comment: The direct proof is somewhat involved but each of its steps is reasonably tractable: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof that avoids heavy calculations with triple indexed matrix entries (at the cost of being quite abstract):
Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional space over a field $k$.
One can show that the vector space of alternating multilinear $n$-forms (that is, maps $V^n\to k$ that are linear in each component and such that the result is zero if two input components are equal) is one-dimensional. 
The determinant of $n\times n$-matrices  is such an alternating multilinear $n$-form (in the $n$ columns of matrices) and is uniquely determined within this one-dimensional space by the fact that $\det I_n=1$ (in fact, this can be used as definition of $\det$). For any matrix $A$, the map $X\mapsto \det(AX)$ is also an alternating multilinear $n$-form, hence is a scalar multiple of $\det$, i.e. $\det(AX)=\alpha\det(X)$ for some $\alpha$ depending on $A$. By comparing values for $X=I_n$, we conclude that $\alpha=\det(A)$.

Comment: @eitzen how do you show such a multilinear form is one dimensional.

Comment: @abel Since $\dim V$ plays a role, at some point one *has* to pick a basis of $V$ and argue with it. So, yes, this step does hide some amount of footwork. It may be somewhat easier if you show the more general result that the number of a.m. $r$-forms is $n\choose r$ (which suggests a way to prove the claim by recursion and merely splitting $V$ into some $\langle v\rangle\oplus W$)

Comment: @eitzen thanks.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is this distribution of determinant is defined over square matrices that are not of same size? Like, we can consider a $1×1$ matrix (a scalar say "k") when multiplied by  a matrix then the resulting determinant will be $(k^{order of matrix})$(times the initial determinant) , but what about other orders?